# What is the default mount point on Linux systems (all)?

Tags: linux, mount, media, removable

My question is very basic in nature. Is the mount point for external media (like USB) always `/media`?

Because in a Debian system, if I plug in any USB device that goes to the `/media` folder. So is it the case with all the other Linux flavors like [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), etc. If a USB device is automatically mounted will it always go to the /media directory?

I am not concerned about the name of the devices. I am looking for every external media (like USB) to be listed under `/media` directory so that my code can run on any flavor of Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Well, up until a few years ago every distro did it their own way. Now there is a standard for directory layout (the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), FHS) which most distros follow.

According to FHS, Media goes under /media. So yes, if your distro complies with FHS (most do), then mounted media will go under /media.

One catch: The FHS does not exhaustively describe how the entry under /media will be named. The names `floppy, cdrom, cdrecorder, zip` must be used, but there's no standard (yet) for USB drives. Also, there may be multiple drives, in which case numbers will be appended.